# Why is the html() function from Ajax creating an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to output an animation while the database operation is in progress. When the db operation is finished, the contents of the table in the html document will be modified.

```
<script>
  var jobj = new Object();
  jobj.uid = <?php echo "'".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";?>;
  var jsoninfo = JSON.stringify(jobj); 
  var table_content = '';

  jQuery.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"./get_sunda.php",
    contentType : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    data : jsoninfo,
    success:function(data)
    {
      var parse_data = JSON.parse(data);
      var array_unik = parse_data.shift();
      var array_heat = parse_data.shift();
      var f_omni = parse_data.shift();
      var i = 0;
      var j = 0;      
      table_content = $('#tblReport').html();
      console.log(0);
      table_content += some_text;
      $('#tblReport').html(table_content);      
      document.getElementById('Load').style.visibility = "hidden";     
    }
  }); 

</script>
```

However, when I call the html () function inside an ajax code, it will fall into an infinite loop even though there is no loop.

[image: Console output]

Comment: When is this function fired?

Comment: can you replicate your code in a jsfiddle?

Comment: interesting, please create jsfiddle or edit with full code.

Comment: What is `some_text`? Please [edit] your question to show the other relevant code.

Comment: @Rajesh 
Thank you! Moving the code from the middle to the end of the document has been resolved.

Comment: @user7608927: always write your scripts at the end of the document, whenever you post script or js code, it is assumed that your script and js code fill be at the end of the document.

Answer (score 2):

Remove your  ajax from any php/js loop, remove any setInterval function you have in the code,

When you bind the ajax to a event you need to make sure the event isn't in a loop/setInterval/another event

Comment: @user7417866 how do you know that this is all his js?

Comment: @user7417866 using only the information provided i can only speculate the cause

Comment: he has written it between <script></script> that mean he don't have any loop into this js code :)

Comment: he moved the js a the bottom of the page so he should have had the script in a php loop

Comment: yup :) we can't predict code written out of scope, if you say apart from this scope yes it make sense.. I was focused to code what is posted here..